# Problems deleting object with nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have some problems with deleting object. I am getting the following error:

> [Test.Item#ab9a9869-b2c1-4262-8d33-9dd9010abd96][SQL: DELETE FROM InvoerItem WHERE DbId = ? AND Version = ?]
>
> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK9100B9F130A0A610". The conflict occurred in database "", table "dbo.InvoerItemToInvoerItem", column 'Listener_id'.

The situation is like this i have an object that has a collection of references to other objects of the same kind these are called listerners.

The mapping for the object looks like this :

```
public InvoerItemMap()
{
    HasManyToMany(x => x.Listeners)
        .ChildKeyColumn("Listener_id")
        .Cascade.None()
        .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);
}
```

What is it that causes the exception when deleting an object that has a listeners connected to it? Do I have to inverse the relation ship of the listeners?

Comment: Who is down-voting here without a comment??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, inverse doesn't help.

you need to specify what you want to do with the listeners. There are basically two options:

- tell the user that there are listeners around and he can't delete this object
- unregister the listeners by the software.

If you decide to unregister the listeners, then ... just implement it.

```
InvoerItem itemToDelete = ...;
itemToDelete.Listeners.Clear();
session.Delete(itemToDelete);
```

It would be even better to let the entity manage the listeners:

```
itemToDelete.UnregisterListeners();
```

**Edit**: if you have references from the listeners to the invoerItems, you need to remove them as well:

```
public void UnregisterListeners()
{
    foreach(Listener listener in Listeners)
    {
        listener.Invoeritem = null;
    }
    Listeners.Clear();
}
```

By the way: in this case you *should* make the listeners inverse. Don't forget to map it to the same foreign key.

Comment: Thank you for your comment

I did the above but i still get the same error. I have added a method called Unregister and there i clear the list. Do i have to ajust the mapping or something ?

Comment: Are there references from the listeners to the InvoerItems? Then you need to remove them as well.

Comment: There exists a circular reference. But i cant delete it because then i get a stackoverflow exception.

Comment: Then it is not an NH related problem I guess. You should be able to fix it just by implementing the classes correctly. If you need further advise there, ask another question which is not NH related (if so).